# Pell like equation solution

Tags: number-theory

If I am looking for solutions of $x^2-2y^2= 24n+23,$

for $ n \in \mathbb N$ and I want to know if there are patterns to the solutions  i.e. perhaps are the $x,y$ dependent on $24n+23$ in any interesting ways?

Comment: It's unnecessary to specify $x$, $y$ both odd, since $x^2-2y^2=24x+23$ has no solutions with $2\mid xy$. (If $x$ is even, the left hand side is even, but the right hand side is always odd. If $y$ is even, then $x^2-2y^2\equiv x^2$ mod $8$, but $24n+23\equiv-1$ mod $8$, and $-1$ is not a square mod $8$.)

Comment: I made the change thank you

Comment: But what are you looking for? Triples of integers $(x,y,n)$? A way of generating infinitely many solutions? A way of parametrizing each and every possible solution? At least to me, It's not so clear what you're looking for...

Comment: I apologize for being vague. I was just curious if there are any interesting properties like either $x = 0 \mod 3$ or $y = 0 \mod 3$ or mod 5,11 etc. Just interested in knowing more.

Answer (score 1):

This says  $x^2 - 2y^2 \cong 23 \pmod{24}$, which has solutions when $x,y$ have residues in $\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}$ modulo $24$.  For integers $x$, and $y$, this is when both $x$ and $y$ are odd and neither is divisible by $3$.  Then for any such pair $x$,$y$, we have $n = \frac{1}{24}(x^2 -2y^2 - 23)$ is an integer.

The easiest way to see that $n$ is an integer is to just look at the $64$ cases.  \begin{align*}
&x & &y & &24(n) = x^2 -2 y^2 - 23 \\
1+{}&24 k & 1+{}&24 m & &24(-1 + 2k + 24k^2 - 4m - 48m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 5+{}&24 m & &24(-3 + 2k + 24 k^2 - 20 m-48 m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 7+{}&24 m & &24(-5 + 2k + 24k^2 - 28 m - 48m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 11+{}&24 m & &24(-11 + 2k + 24k^2 - 44 m - 48m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 13+{}&24 m & &24(-15 + 2k + 24k^2 - 52 m - 48m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 17+{}&24 m & &24(-25 + 2k + 24k^2 - 68 m - 48m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 19+{}&24 m & &24(-31 + 2k + 24k^2 - 76 m - 48m^2)  \\
1+{}&24 k & 23+{}&24 m & &24(-45 + 2k + 24k^2 - 92 m - 48m^2)  \\
5+{}&24 k & 1+{}&24 m & &24(0 + 10k + 24k^2 - 4m - 48m^2)  \\
&\vdots & &\vdots &&\quad \vdots
\end{align*}